# Forcing download in Safari keeps window open

Tags: php, safari, download

I'm forcing a download on links using this code from the PHP.net site:

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

I put this code in a file called 'download.php', and call it from a page (`<a href="download.php?file=abc.doc">Click</a>`).

It works fine on all browsers, but on Safari the window it opens ('download.php') stays open during and after the download/open process. In other browsers it disappears immediately. Has anyone else come across this problem, and if so are there any suggestions as to how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and it seems to be working equally in all browsers. Try this code, considering that Safari and IE need of more characters as headers to be sent:

```
#$file = 'load.php';
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();

for($i = 0; $i < 40000; $i++) {
    echo ' '; // extra spaces
}
flush();
usleep(50000);
exit;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried the code but a) it now makes the file unreadable (trying with a .doc file); b) the blank window holding download.php still remains open in Safari.

Comment: @Greg, could you please provide the entire code (also where `$file` is declared) and the tries you have done?

Comment: Ha, thanks for your suggestion. In the process of copying the code just now I realised what the problem was. I'd put target="_blank" in the anchor tag that called download.php. I've removed it now and it works fine. Thanks for your help.